# Change facebook page app height

Tags: facebook, iframe, height

Just before i start, i have searched for a long time and read many posts,
the Facebook page app is different from a normal app, at least when it comes to height.

I have a facebook page app (runs inside a facebook page) that runs inside facebook's iframe.
the iframe has a specifc height that i want to change to avoid inner scroll bar.

[link](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Test/116248295095196#!/pages/Test/116248295095196?sk=app_123770137768831)

there is nothing about the height parameters inside the app settings.

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go into http://facebook.com/developers -> click to your app -> "Basic" menu item -> and there is the section called **App on Facebook** . There are parameters of canvas (**width** and **height**).

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but as i said, this is not a App on Facebook but a Page Tab.
i don't have these settings